# How to get a reverse animation of ActivityOptions.makeScaleUpAnimation when finishing child activity on android?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, scale, android-4.2-jelly-bean

After JellyBean, Android SDK includes an ActivityOptions.makeScaleUpAnimation() API for starting an activity using scale-up animation from a view. I want to know how i can get a reverse animation that scales down the activity window to the original view when finishing the activity?
And another question is that can i define the animation duration when using ActivityOptions.makeScaleUpAnimation()?

Answer (score 1):

Unforunatly that is currently not possible.  Check this video from the android dev blog http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ho8vk61lVIU.

I'm not sure about the duration, you might have to subclass ActivityOptions.

Comment: But i notice that Google Keep does exactly that when the user select a note to see its content from the main list. I wonder how they did that.

Comment: I'm guessing that their animating a fragment or a view to handle it. It's probably not a new activity.